# data-sly-resource error handling in sightly - AEM

Tags: aem, sightly

[`data-sly-resource`](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/htl/docs/block-statements.html#resource) tag allows to refer resource in another component in following way.

```
<article data-sly-resource="path/to/resource"></article>
```

We have `path/to/resource` being taken as part of dialog field by content authors. If the content authors select the path which is not existing by mistake, page becomes inaccessible to content authors, giving HTTP 500 error and there is no other way to correct it without going to CRX. On environments where access to CRX is not there, we cannot delete the incorrect node. Exception in logs is

```
Caused by: org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.SightlyException: org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceNotFoundException: No resource found
at com.adobe.cq.sightly.WCMScriptHelper.includeResource(WCMScriptHelper.java:143)
at com.adobe.cq.sightly.WCMScriptHelper.includeResource(WCMScriptHelper.java:86)
at com.adobe.cq.sightly.internal.extensions.ResourceExtension.call(ResourceExtension.java:99)
at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.runtime.RenderContextImpl.call(RenderContextImpl.java:89)
```

The out of the box [reference component](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/author/page-authoring/default-components/editmode.html#Reference) (/libs/foundation/components/reference/reference.jsp) handles this by having a catch block, Content Author can correct path. But that's JSP based not sightly based.

Is there a way to handle this in sightly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to handle this is through an Use-API object that will attempt to find the resource and handle any exceptions:

```
<article data-sly-use.helper="myHelper" data-sly-test="${helper.resource}" data-sly-resource="${helper.resource}"></article>
```

Passing an actual `org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource` to `data-sly-resource` is possible since [SLING-5811](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-5811), for older versions of HTL/Sightly you will need to pass a path.

Comment: May be creating a custom tag would have also helped. But it seems [that is not allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36335327/aem-sightly-is-it-possible-to-create-custom-data-sly-attributes)

Answer (score -1):

Try this syntax, path should given in EL expression:

```
<article data-sly-resource="${ @ path='path/to/resource'}"></article>
```

Comment: <article data-sly-resource="${ @ path='path/to/resource'}"></article>